# What does the status "editor discussion period" in editorial manager mean?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have this on editorial manager, but I can't find any information about what it is/means anywhere!
It's been this way for 15 odd days, and before that, it was "under review" (I may have missed some steps in the middle because I didn't check for 3 weeks).

Comment: No it doesn't really, because I've never heard about an "editor discussion period" and I was wondering whether someone else had.

Comment: And that response doesn't say anything about an "editor discussion period"

Comment: They've probably received the reviews and are discussing those reviews. Perhaps it's a new editor who want some guidance. Perhaps one of the reviewers did a bad job and the editor needs to decide whether to find another reviewer. Perhaps the reviews are so inconsistent with each other that the handling editor wants to talk it through with someone else to work out what to ask you to do. This is all speculation based on the plain english reading of the phrased used.

Comment: My initial guess would be this is something like "Decision Pending," but I don't know why it would be like this for 15 days since usually the decision should be 1-2 days max. It also could be that it's being sent out for a 3rd or 4th reviewer, but then it should return to "Peer Review" or "Under Review" or something like that.  This seems unusual enough that perhaps it's worth a note to the editor to ask about the status? In any case, if no one chimes in with a proper answer it would be great for you to return to answer your own question once you find out what actually DID happen to the paper.

Comment: Fair enough, that's what I thought as well, but I was curious to know to know if anyone had encountered the same status before. I'll definitely post the answer here if I ever find out what happened!

Answer (score 2):

If as you say this "editor discussion period" occurred after the manuscript was reviewed, but before you received a formal decision, then this probably corresponds to the "Editorial decision" section of [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55666/). The editor(s) are making a decision based on the reviews. It should not take very long unless many people are involved in the decision.

Comment: The editor could also be on a holiday themselves, which might stretch up the process duration a bit.